# ORA-01795: maximum number of expressions in a list is 1000 from python and cx_oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, python-3.6, cx-oracle

I'm passing empList which is having 500k records as an input to my query, but my python cx_oracle code failing with below error. 
I need result for all those 500k records. How to get this without creating a temp table? It would be good if i pass it as a list or dataframe.

Error :

> cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-01795: maximum number of expressions in a list is 1000

```
curs.execute("select ID,NAME,SAL from EMP where ID in "+str(tuple(empList))+"  ")
```

**Solution ::**
I've resolved the issue by splitting and sending 1000 records each time like below. And performance wise also good.

```
repeat = 1
for i in range(0, len(myList), 1000):
    for j in range(i, 1000*repeat):
        if j+1 <= len(myList):
            tempList.append(myList[j])
    //Further processing logic
    tempList = []
    repeat += 1
```

Comment: If you're just fetching records, you could also do it in batches of 1000 ids

Answer (score 0):

Oracle does allow > 1000 Tuples but not simple values. [More on this here](https://community.oracle.com/message/3515498#3515498) and [here](https://community.oracle.com/thread/958612),

You could make use of Tuples

```
SELECT ID, NAME, SAL
FROM EMP
WHERE (1, ID) IN ((1, value1), (1, value2), (1, value3),.....(1, value5000));
```

This is of course if you don't have the option of using a subquery inside IN to get the values you need from a temp table.

```
SELECT ID, NAME, SAL FROM EMP where ID IN (SELECT values from <temporary-table>);
```

Comment: First link requires a support account in Oracle.